# How to write and read a file with a HashMap?

Tags: java, file, dictionary, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` with two Strings `Map<String, String> ldapContent = new HashMap<String, String>`.

Now I want to save the `Map` in an external file to use the `Map` later without initializing it again...

So how must I save the `Map` to use it later again?

Comment: What have you tried? You can use Java serialization, XML, CSV, binary data manually...

Comment: i just know the simple filereader. therefore thank for the serialization tip. i don't know it before...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`HashMap` implements `Serializable` so you can use normal serialization to write hashmap to file

Here is the link for [Java - Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) example

Answer (score 51):

The simplest solution that I can think of is using Properties class.

Saving the map:

```
Map<String, String> ldapContent = new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties properties = new Properties();

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : ldapContent.entrySet()) {
    properties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

properties.store(new FileOutputStream("data.properties"), null);
```

Loading the map:

```
Map<String, String> ldapContent = new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("data.properties"));

for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
   ldapContent.put(key, properties.get(key).toString());
}
```

EDIT:

if your map contains plaintext values, they will be visible if you open file data via any text editor, which is not the case if you serialize the map:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.ser"));
out.writeObject(ldapContent);
out.close();
```

EDIT2:

instead of for loop (as suggested by OldCurmudgeon) in saving example:

```
properties.putAll(ldapContent);
```

however, for the loading example this is the best that can be done:

```
ldapContent = new HashMap<Object, Object>(properties);
```

Comment: As `Properties` implements `Map` you should be able to use `putAll` to populate it. Also, since `HashMap` has a `HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)` constructor you should be able to populate it on construction for the same reason.

Comment: I agree, it simplifies the solution

Comment: This solution does not maintain the order from Hashmap. Is there something that can write to the file from a TreeMap where insertion order is maintained in the map?

Answer (score 24):

since `HashMap` implements `Serializable` interface, you can simply use `ObjectOutputStream` class to write whole `Map` to file, and read it again using `ObjectInputStream` class

below simple code that explain usage of `ObjectOutStream` and `ObjectInputStream`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class A{

    HashMap<String,String> hm;
    public A() {
        hm=new HashMap<String,String>();

        hm.put("1","A");
        hm.put("2","B");
        hm.put("3","C");

        method1(hm);

    }

public void method1(HashMap<String,String> map) {
    //write to file : "fileone"
    try {
        File fileOne=new File("fileone");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileOne);
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(map);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {}

    //read from file 
    try {
        File toRead=new File("fileone");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        HashMap<String,String> mapInFile=(HashMap<String,String>)ois.readObject();

        ois.close();
        fis.close();
        //print All data in MAP
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> m :mapInFile.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" : "+m.getValue());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {}
  }

public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A();
}

}
```

or if you want to write data as text to file you can simply iterate through `Map` and write key and value line by line, and read it again line by line and add to `HashMap`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class A{

    HashMap<String,String> hm;
    public A(){
        hm=new HashMap<String,String>();

        hm.put("1","A");
        hm.put("2","B");
        hm.put("3","C");

        method2(hm);

    }

public void method2(HashMap<String,String> map) {
    //write to file : "fileone"
    try {
        File fileTwo=new File("filetwo.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileTwo);
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fos);

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> m :map.entrySet()){
            pw.println(m.getKey()+"="+m.getValue());
        }

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {}

    //read from file 
    try {
        File toRead=new File("filetwo.txt");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);

        HashMap<String,String> mapInFile=new HashMap<String,String>();

        //read data from file line by line:
        String currentLine;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            currentLine=sc.nextLine();
            //now tokenize the currentLine:
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(currentLine,"=",false);
            //put tokens ot currentLine in map
            mapInFile.put(st.nextToken(),st.nextToken());
        }
        fis.close();

        //print All data in MAP
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> m :mapInFile.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" : "+m.getValue());
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {}
  }

public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A();
}

}
```

NOTE: above code may not be the fastest way to doing this task, but i want to show some application of classes

See [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) , [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can write an object to a file using `writeObject` in ObjectOutputStream

[ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)