# jackson objectMapper.readValue fails on empty values

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to read this json file into a Map
{
"1": 0,
"2": 1,
"3": ,
"4": 5
}
my json is very simple but as you see in the example it can have a key with an empty value (null value) on "3".
parsing it by:

```
    Map<String, Object> testMap = objectMapper.readValue(file.getInputStream(), Map.class);
```

fails with "Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a value"

is there any way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747946/how-to-write-and-read-a-file-with-a-hashmap

Comment: This string `{ "1": 0, "2" 1, "3": , "4": 5 }` is not a valid JSON string:  delimiter `:` is missing in `"2" 1` fragment, _value_ is missing after `"3"` key.  Check the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) -- no _empty_ number can be used as a value.  Thus, Jackson library does not have to be able to read such malformed JSON sources.

Comment: @AlexRudenko i edited the json for the missing delimiter.

Comment: @AlexRudenko thanks, I edited the json for the missing delimiter.  I need to have the possibility to have a key with null value... but I understand from what you wrote that it's not a valid json.

Comment: still not a json, the correct json would have "3":null

Answer (score 1):

`{ "1": 0, "2": 1, "3": , "4": 5 }` is not a valid JSON, so any standard parser would fail. You can customize a parser or (better) use a regex to substitute the `"key": ,` with `"key": null,`.